# React populating a dropdown from an input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, dropdown

I have a simple React app that allows you to create multiple "story" components when you click a button. Each "story" has two components - an input field (to edit the story title) and a dropdown list (showing all other story titles).

I’m trying to get the story dropdown list to populate with all the story titles (at the moment they are hard coded to a state array called storyOptions).

The end idea is - User creates new story > user updates story title > user chooses another story to link to from the dropdown (dropdown shows the titles of all the other stories).

My current code is below...

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.storyList = [];
    this.state = {storys: this.storyList};
  }

  addNewStory(e) {
    this.storyList.push({
      id: this.storyList.length,
      title:"Type your story title here",
    });
    this.setState({storys: this.storyList});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <button className="square" onClick={() => this.addNewStory()}>
            "Add new story"
          </button>
          <div>
              {this.state.storys.map(c => <StoryComponent key={c.id} title={c.title} />)}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
export default class StoryComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          defaultStoryOption: 0,
          title: this.props.title
        };
        this.storyOptions = [
            'Story 1', 'Story 2'
        ]
        this.handleQuestionChange = this.handleQuestionChange.bind(this);
        this.storyOptionChange = this.storyOptionChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleTitleChange(e) {
        console.log("Title is being updated");
        this.setState({title: e.target.value});
    }

    storyOptionChange(e) {
    }

    getListOfStories() {
        return this.storyOptions;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="StoryComponent">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <Dropdown options={this.getListOfStories()} onChange={this.storyOptionChange} value={this.storyOptions[this.state.defaultStoryOption]} placeholder="Select a story" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to fetch the drop-down values from the server?

Comment: not via the server, i’m looking for the dropdown to populate from all of the story titles. i.e this.storyOptions in StoryComponent is actually generated based on each story title (number of stories depends on how many the user has added).

Comment: so your story options will be your story title?

Comment: Yep exactly! Every time i add a new StoryComponent the dropdown should increase (adding the story title from the new StoryComponent)

Comment: Try passing you `storys` as a prop to StoryComponent and set that prop to options in Drop-down component

Comment: That works until you need to edit a story title. I.e when you edit a story title how do you then update the dropdown list? You can’t directly edit a prop. I’ve tried most things so need a code example

Comment: could you please create a fiddle and share to check the issue?

Comment: I've solved the issue now but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. Trick was to store the titles as an array in App, then pass the titles down to both the dropdown and the input fields in StoryComponent as props.

```
handleTitleChange(e) {
    console.log("Title is being updated");
    this.setState({title: e.target.value});
}
```

Changed to...

```
handleTitleChange(e) {
    console.log("Title is being updated");
    this.props.onQuestionUpdate(e); // pass the value back up to App.
}
```

And inside App I now have...

```
private onQuestionUpdate(e:any) {
    let storys = this.state.storys;
    storys[Number(e.target.id)] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({storys: storys});
}
```